# Javascript Object Undefined - Jquery + Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm facing this problem and I'm a newbie with Javascript and NodeJS, below I have this code at my Route on `/update/:id`

```
controller.save = (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body
  const name = req.body.name
  const cpf = req.body.cpf
  req.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    const query = connection.query(
      `INSERT INTO clientes(Nome, CPF) 
    VALUES('${name}','${cpf}')`,
      data,
      (err, clientes) => {
        res.json(clientes)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

and I have a form that have a Button called "Update", when I click , the AJAX made this .

```
$(document).on("click", ".update", function() {
  var user_id = $(this).attr("id")
  $.ajax({
    url: "/update/" + user_id,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(to) {
      alert(to)
    }
  })
})
```

I'm receive a alert `[Object Object]`, when I go to my Network response I have this:

```
  [{"ID":5,"Nome":"tobiaas","CPF":"107"}]
```

when I change alert to `alert(to.Nome)`, I receive a alert `Undefined`

I don't wanna use .map, because i thing that this is a simple way to made work .

Comment: First, that's an array of JSON, you need to do something like `alert(to[0].Nome)` if you want to access it. Aside from that I fail to see your problem.

Comment: thanks , i was trying make : alert(to.Nome[0]) . like u say work it .

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an array as the response, `Array.Nome` does not exists, your output is normal.

You need to get the item with `response[0]` or `response.pop()` to access it:

```
success: function(response) {
  const to = response[0]
  alert(to.Nome)
}
```

For more info on javascript array access, see [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: had the same effect as the alert (to)